# Is there a way I can check if src of an img tag is containing a specific string for scraping using BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape all images from 6th column in a table, based on there src attribute. Because there are other images in column 1 also. So I an shortlisting images based on specific src.

The link I want to scrape is https://reelgood.com/tv and I only scrape the 6th column  that contains channel logos with this image tag values< img src="https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg" alt="hbo_max" >. I only want to check if all images that I scrape contains "img.reelgood.com/service-logos". so that I only get logos.

Comment: Try to be more specific. What website? What table? What do you exactly want to do? Provide more details.

Comment: I made a quick edit on your request,

Comment: Ok...That's great! But what have u tried so far?

Comment: I tried images = soup.find_all('div', class_='css-1flk2s8 e11eoopx0')
results in <div class="css-1flk2s8 e11eoopx0"><img alt="netflix" src="https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg"/></div>

Comment: I only want to get the alt (means netflix here) of the image, to check if this channel exists in the list of allowed channels by the client.

Comment: Ok...Check out my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://reelgood.com/tv')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html5lib')

divs = soup.find_all('div', class_ = lambda value: value == 'css-1flk2s8 e11eoopx0' or value == 'css-1lcdwq3 e11eoopx0' or value == 'css-1d5ll0r e11eoopx0')

[print(f"Streamer = {div.img['alt']} , Image = {div.img['src']}") for div in divs]
```

Output:

```
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = hoopla , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hoopla.svg
Streamer = adult_swim_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/adult_swim.svg
Streamer = adult_swim , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/adult_swim.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = fx_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fx.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = amazon_prime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amazon_prime.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = cbs_all_access , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/cbs_all_access.svg
Streamer = hoopla , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hoopla.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = philo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/philo.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = comedycentral_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/comedy.svg
Streamer = comedy , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/comedy.svg
Streamer = southpark , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/southpark.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = tbs , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/tbs.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = thecw , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/thecw.svg
Streamer = tnt , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/tnt.svg
Streamer = disney_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/disney_plus.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = crunchyroll_premium , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/crunchyroll.svg
Streamer = funimation , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/funimation.svg
Streamer = tubi_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/tubi_tv.svg
Streamer = crunchyroll_free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/crunchyroll.svg
Streamer = adult_swim_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/adult_swim.svg
Streamer = adult_swim , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/adult_swim.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = philo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/philo.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = comedycentral_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/comedy.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = philo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/philo.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = amc_premiere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amc_premiere.svg
Streamer = amc , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amc.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = amazon_prime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amazon_prime.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = philo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/philo.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = peacock_free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/peacock.svg
Streamer = comedycentral_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/comedy.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = amazon_prime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amazon_prime.svg
Streamer = peacock , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/peacock.svg
Streamer = nbc_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/nbc.svg
Streamer = nbc , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/nbc.svg
Streamer = amazon_prime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amazon_prime.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = disney_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/disney_plus.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = fx_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fx.svg
Streamer = fox_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fox.svg
Streamer = fox , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fox.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = showtime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/showtime.svg
Streamer = showtime_free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/showtime.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = amazon_prime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amazon_prime.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = peacock , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/peacock.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = tbs , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/tbs.svg
Streamer = nbc_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/nbc.svg
Streamer = nbc , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/nbc.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = imdb_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/imdb_tv.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = hbo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = showtime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/showtime.svg
Streamer = cbs_all_access , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/cbs_all_access.svg
Streamer = hbo_max , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hbo_max.svg
Streamer = tbs , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/tbs.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = amc_premiere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amc_premiere.svg
Streamer = imdb_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/imdb_tv.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = abc_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/abc.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
Streamer = youtube_premium , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/youtube_premium.svg
Streamer = youtube_premium_free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/youtube_premium.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = amazon_prime , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/amazon_prime.svg
Streamer = peacock_free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/peacock.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = crunchyroll_premium , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/crunchyroll.svg
Streamer = funimation , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/funimation.svg
Streamer = crunchyroll_free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/crunchyroll.svg
Streamer = adult_swim_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/adult_swim.svg
Streamer = adult_swim , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/adult_swim.svg
Streamer = free , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/free.svg
Streamer = imdb_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/imdb_tv.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = tbs , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/tbs.svg
Streamer = hulu_plus , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/hulu.svg
Streamer = philo , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/philo.svg
Streamer = fubo_tv , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fubo_tv.svg
Streamer = fx_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fx.svg
Streamer = viceland_tve , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/viceland.svg
Streamer = fox_tveverywhere , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/fox.svg
Streamer = netflix , Image = https://img.reelgood.com/service-logos/netflix.svg
```

Comment: why does it only extract 39 results? There are 50 row of TV shows in the table and each row contains at least 1 channel logo (actually some rows have more than 1 logo)? In that way there should be at least 50 results but they are only 39. This is bothering me.

Comment: Actually there should be 167 but only 94 are extracted.

Comment: Oh...Check out my latest edit. The actual number of images to be extracted are 151 and my latest code extracts all images.